# Removing duplicates with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a similar issue to this [No duplicates in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543435/no-duplicates-in-sql-query)

Please [find here the sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99ea1/1)

I have this:

```
+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| TAFIELDA |   DESCRIPTION   | TBFIELDA | TBFIELDB | DOCNUMBER | TCFIELDB |
+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|     1000 | some data       |     2000 |     1000 |       525 |     2000 |
|     1001 | some other data |     2000 |     1001 |       525 |     2000 |
+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Expected result:

```
+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| TAFIELDA |   DESCRIPTION   | TBFIELDA | TBFIELDB | DOCNUMBER | TCFIELDB |
+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|     1001 | some other data |     2000 |     1001 |       525 |     2000 |
+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I need only the highest `TAFIELDA` value with the `DocNumber = 525`, so I did this:

```
SELECT max(tAFieldA) tAFieldA,DocNumber
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TAFIELDA = B.TBFIELDB
INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON B.tBFieldA = C.tCFieldB
where DocNumber = 525
group by (DocNumber)
```

That query returns me only the row I'm looking for, the problem is that If I add another field that could not be summary, for example `Description`, I get again several records.

¿How could I obtain only one record per `DocNumber` with all the fields of the [sample DB](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99ea1/1)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS SQL 2008 : Delete "duplicates" to select most recent results using multiple columns with no PK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22438543/ms-sql-2008-delete-duplicates-to-select-most-recent-results-using-multiple-c).  Dealing with duplicates is one of the most common questions we get here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Sub-Query**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DOCNUMBER ORDER BY tAFieldA DESC) rn
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TAFIELDA = B.TBFIELDB
INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON B.tBFieldA = C.tCFieldB
) Sub 
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Using CTE**

```
;WITH CTE
 AS
   (
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DOCNUMBER ORDER BY tAFieldA DESC) rn
    FROM TABLEA A
    INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TAFIELDA = B.TBFIELDB
    INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON B.tBFieldA = C.tCFieldB
   )
 SELECT * FROM CTE
 WHERE rn = 1
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99ea1/16)

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TAFIELDA = B.TBFIELDB
INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON B.tBFieldA = C.tCFieldB
WHERE TAFIELDA IN (
  SELECT max(tAFieldA)
    FROM TABLEA A
   INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON A.TAFIELDA = B.TBFIELDB
   INNER JOIN TABLEC C ON B.tBFieldA = C.tCFieldB
   WHERE DocNumber = 525
   GROUP BY (DocNumber)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.* ,b.* ,c.* 
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on a.tafielda = b.tbfieldb
inner join tablec c on b.tbfielda = c.tcfieldb
where (tafielda,docnumber) in
    (
        select max(tafielda) tafielda,docnumber
        from tablea a
        inner join tableb b on a.tafielda = b.tbfieldb
        inner join tablec c on b.tbfielda = c.tcfieldb
        where docnumber = 525
        group by (docnumber)
    )
```

Comment: hi Andy how you edited it ,i put the formatted code as you edited but after posting,it did't appear as it is now ,how u do it ???